# Can't get an acronym generating function to work for the last input word on python

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string of words as an input and prints the first letter of each word, upper-cased, as an acronym. the closest I have got is writing this function that works only for the first two words - how can I get it to work for every word in the list, no matter how many words separated by a space the input string contains?

Here's the code I am running:

```
def fxn(stng):
    out=stng[0]
    for i in range(1, len(stng)):
        if stng[i-1]==' ':
            out+=stng[i]
            out=out.upper()
            return out
input1=input()
print(fxn(input1))
```

This is an example of an input and the output I'm currently getting. I would expect it to be `SOS`.

```
save our souls
SO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it doesn't go through your whole string. As soon as it arrives on a new word (it goes into your if statement), it adds the initial of this word and immediately exits the function.

So, you have to go through your whole string (ie your for loop must end) then you return the result.

```py
def fxn(stng):
    out=stng[0]
    for i in range(1, len(stng)):
        if stng[i-1]==' ':
            out+=stng[i]
            out=out.upper()
    # return outside of for loop      
    return out

input1=input()
print(fxn(input1))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot easier way to go about this, which is to split your string into words based on the space delimiter and then take the first of each:

```
first_letters = [w[0].upper() for w in input_str.split(' ')]
output = "".join(first_letters)
```

All this is doing is using the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function to split up your string into words, and then for each word, in a list comprehension, it is taking the first letter (`w[0]`), upper-casing it and saving it to a list. Then we can use `join` to concatenate them together.